# Django list of item did not appear

Tags: python, django

I created model, view and template for display list of items in template but after I run the website It didn't anything. Please help me to solve this.

model.py

```
class waterLevel(models.Model):

height = models.CharField(max_length=250)
date = DateTimeField(max_length=250)

def __str__(self):
# #
    return self.height + '-' + self.date
```

view.py

```
def compare(request):

    all_waterLevels = waterLevel.objects.all()
    context = {'all_waterLevels': all_waterLevels}
    return render(request, 'Home/compare.html', context)
```

compare.html

```
 {% if all_waterLevels %}


    <ul>
      {% for height in all_waterLevels %}
        <li><a href="/Home/compare{{ waterLevel.id }}/"> {{ waterLevel.height }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Home/compare{{ waterLevel.id }}/"> {{ waterLevel.date }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}

    </ul>
{% else %}
    <h3>no any details</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If you're using 'for height in all_waterLevels' then you should use 'height.height' and 'height.date'

Comment: is models.py formatted in same way as you have mentioned??? and does table have entries?

Comment: It works.Thank you.
I wasted more than 3 hours in this.
Thanks you again

Comment: Totally unrelated but you should use the `{% url '<urlname>' <args> %}` templatetag instead of hardcoding your urls in the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
{% if all_waterLevels %}


<ul>
  {% for waterLevel in all_waterLevels %}
    <li><a href="/Home/compare{{ waterLevel.id }}/"> {{ waterLevel.height }}</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Home/compare{{ waterLevel.id }}/"> {{ waterLevel.date }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}

</ul>
{% else %}
    <h3>no any details</h3>
{% endif %}
```